# Why does Haskell 9.0 not have Zero in its linear types, but Idris 2 does?

Tags: haskell, types, idris, linear-types

From the Idris 2 publication about linear types ["Idris 2: Quantitative Type Theory in Practice"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.00480.pdf):

> For Idris 2, we make a concrete choice of semiring, where a multiplicity can be one of:
>
> - 0: the variable is not used at run time
> - 1: the variable is used exactly once at run time
> - ω: no restrictions on the variable’s usage at run time

But for [Haskell](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0111-linear-types.rst#current-status):

> In the fashion of levity polymorphism, the proposal introduces a data type `Multiplicity` which is treated specially by the type checker, to represent the multiplicities:
>
> ```
> data Multiplicity
>   = One    -- represents 1
>   | Many   -- represents ω
> ```

Why didn't they add a Zero?

Comment: The linear types proposal has a section about possibly adding more multiplicities: https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0111-linear-types.rst#more-multiplicities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Idris, the value of a function argument can appear in the return type. You might write a function with type

```
vecLen : (n : Nat) -> Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)
```

This says "`vecLen` is a function that takes a `Nat` (call it `n`) and a `Vect` of length `n` and element type `a` and returns a `Nat` (call it `m`) such that `n = m`". The intent is to walk the linked list `Vect` and come up with its length as a runtime `Nat` value. But the issue is that `vecLen` requires you to already *have* the length of the vector as a runtime value, because that's the very `n` argument we're talking about! I.e. it's possible to implement just

```
vecLen n _ = (n ** Refl) -- does no real work
```

You can't *not* take `n` as an argument, because the `Vect` type *needs* its length as an argument to make sense. This is a somewhat serious problem, because having both `n` and a `Vect n a` *duplicates* information—without intervention the "classic" definition of `Vect n a` itself is in fact space-quadratic in `n`! So we need a way to take an argument that we know "in principle exists" but may not "actually exist" at runtime. That's what the zero multiplicity is for.

```
vecLen : (0 n : Nat) -> Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)
-- old definition invalid, you MUST iterate over the Vect to collect information on n (which is what we want!)
vecLen _ [] = (0 ** Refl)
vecLen _ (_ :: xs) with (vecLen _ xs)
    vecLen _ (_ :: xs) | (n ** Refl) = (S n ** Refl)
```

This is the use of the zero multiplicity in Idris: it lets you talk about values that may not exist yet/anymore/ever inside of types so you can reason about them etc. (I believe in one talk Edwin Brady did, he used or at least noted you could use zero multiplicities to reason about the previous state of a mutable resource.)

But Haskell does not quite have this kind of dependent typing... so there just isn't a use case for zero multiplicities. From another point of view, the zero multiplicity form of `f :: a -> b` is just `f :: forall (x :: a). b`, because Haskell is wholesale type-erased in a way that Idris and other dependently typed languages cannot easily be. (In this sense, IMO, I think Haskell has the whole dependent type erasure problem that other languages have such trouble with neatly solved—at the cost of having to use an awkward encoding for everything else about dependent types!)

In the latter sense, the "dependent" Haskell (i.e. souped-up with `singletons`) way to take a dependent, unrestricted argument is this:

```
--        vvvvvv +  vvvvvvvv duplicate information!
vecLen :: SNat n -> Vect n a -> SNat n
vecLen n _ = n -- allowed, ergh!
```

and the "zero multiplicity" version is just

```
vecLen :: Vect n a -> SNat n
-- must walk Vect, cannot match on erased types like n
vecLen Nil = SZ
vecLen (_ `Cons` xs) = SS (goodLen xs)
```

Comment: maybe this is a stupid question - why we want to write in idris 2 `vecLen : (0 n : Nat) -> Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)` instead of `vecLen : Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)` if `n` is not used?

Comment: @srghma As it says [in the manual](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/multiplicities.html), `Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)` is nothing but shorthand for `{0 n : Nat} -> {0 a : _} -> Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)`. *Something* has to introduce the name `n`! And it *is* used, as part of the *description* of a value (i.e. in a type), just not as a runtime value.

Comment: Will the `vecLen : (0 n : Nat) -> Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)` and `{0 n : Nat} -> {0 a : _} -> Vect n a -> (m : Nat ** n = m)` compile to the same program code if their definition is the same?

Comment: Yes. The only difference between `{}` and `()` is in parsing/typechecking: `{}` arguments are implicit. But they're *there*. In the underlying theory of the language I'm not sure `{}` even exists.

Comment: just like in this `Door` example https://gist.github.com/srghma/e264aee6f985cdc275e76d9aae1c4083